# how to create this matrix without using for loop?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I want to create a N*N matrix A.

```
when n = 4
2  0 -2  0
2  0  2  0
0  2  0 -2
0  2  0  2

when n = 8
2  0  0  0 -2  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  2  0  0  0
0  2  0  0  0 -2  0  0
0  2  0  0  0  2  0  0
0  0  2  0  0  0 -2  0
0  0  2  0  0  0  2  0
0  0  0  2  0  0  0 -2
0  0  0  2  0  0  0  2
```

I can create this using nested for loop, but how to achieve it more efficiently? Are there any methods without for loop?

Thanks

Comment: Check the [`diag`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) function, this one can create off-diagonal elements as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
A = zeros(n);
idx = bsxfun(@plus,[0:(n/2)-1]*((n+3)-1),[1:2].');
A(idx) = 2;
A(idx+numel(A)/2) = -2;
```

Sample runs -

Case #1 :

```
>> n = 4;
>> A
A =
     2     0    -2     0
     2     0    -2     0
     0     2     0    -2
     0     2     0    -2
```

Case #2 :

```
>> n = 8;
>> A
A =
     2     0     0     0    -2     0     0     0
     2     0     0     0    -2     0     0     0
     0     2     0     0     0    -2     0     0
     0     2     0     0     0    -2     0     0
     0     0     2     0     0     0    -2     0
     0     0     2     0     0     0    -2     0
     0     0     0     2     0     0     0    -2
     0     0     0     2     0     0     0    -2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help... :) it works perfectly.

Comment: You will like this: `kron` in recent Matlab versions (from R2014b, maybe earlier) uses `bsxfun` internally!

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes! I think first chappjc told me about this, or he commented on some answer from Ray. Seems like bsxfun is spreading like a good disease all over! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
[reshape([repmat([ 2;2;zeros(n,1)],n/2-1,1); 2;2],n,n/2)   ...
 reshape([repmat([-2;2;zeros(n,1)],n/2-1,1);-2;2],n,n/2) ]
```

This only will work, if `n` is a power of two, obviously.

[EDIT]
It might be faster to use

```
[reshape([repmat([ 2;2;zeros(n,1)],n/2-1,1); 2;2;       ...
          repmat([-2;2;zeros(n,1)],n/2-1,1);-2;2] ,n,n) ]
```

[EDIT2]
This is only a good idea, if you have `n` of moderate size. If you need really big matrices, you should use sparse matrices. In this case a loop is what you want.

Comment: thanks for the help... :) I learn how to use reshape and repmat. and it works perfect for the problem.